# FileMaker PHP API - getField() not returning all values

Tags: php, filemaker

I have a FileMaker PHP script that is designed to echo data from a record back to my iOS application. I'm just starting off with using the FileMaker PHP API, so I'm kind of helpless here.

I'm able to successfully connect to my FileMaker WebServer 15 as well as pull half the data I need from the layout. The problem is that I cannot get all of the data I need for whatever reason. I have tried changing the data types in the FileMaker Database to every different data type possible, even a calculation. I have tried the data with and without spaces, such as making the $F variable = "a123 123 asdf", and it will still only pull a select few fields' data.

Whenever I perform a

```
$layout->listValueLists();
```

or

```
$layout->listFields();
```

it shows that all the fields I'm trying to retrieve data from are on the layout, but for some reason the PHP script cannot return the data from all of them.

Heres the PHP Script:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/php/FileMaker.php');

$fm = new FileMaker();
$fm->setProperty('database', 'xx123 Master DB');
$fm->setProperty('hostspec', '123.456.789.000');
$fm->setProperty('username', 'fmphp');
$fm->setProperty('password', 'xx123');


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$q = $fm -> newFindCommand('Login_Info');
$q -> addFindCriterion('username', '=='.$username);
$q -> addFindCriterion('password', '=='.$password);

$r = $q->execute();

// This is the login portion of the script
if(empty($username) or empty($password)){

    echo '{"message":"User or password field blank", "code":401}';

}elseif(FileMaker::isError($r)){

    if($r->code == 401){
        echo '{"message":"User not found or password incorrect", "code":401}';
    }else{
        echo '{"message":"Unknown Error", code:'.$r->code.'}';
    }

}else{
// This happens if an account has a $username and $password that are found together.
    $account = $r -> getFirstRecord();
    $ID_Account = $account->getField('ID_Account');
    $customername = $account->getField('Customer_Name');
    $username = $account->getField('username');
    $F = $account->getField('ID_Account_F');
    $customername2 = $account->getField('vCustomer_Name');
    $testpull = $account->getField('testpull');
    $logindata = array('ID_Account' => $ID_Account, 'Customer_Name' => $customername, 'User_Name' => $username, 'F_ID' => $F, 'Customer_Name2' => $customername2, 'testpull' => $testpull);
    echo json_encode($logindata);

}

?>
```

This is what the script returns:

```
Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170221ba0> { URL: http://xx123.com/testing.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 114;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 13 Dec 2016 17:02:55 GMT";
    "MS-Author-Via" = DAV;
    Server = "Sucuri/Cloudproxy";
    "X-Sucuri-ID" = xx123;
} }
Data: 114 bytes
JSON: ["F_ID": act1207, "User_Name": test, "Customer_Name": , "Customer_Name2": , "testpull": , "ID_Account": 1002]
```

[Here's my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpeQY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to check all the privileges inside your fmphp webaccess account!

If you're like me and forgot something as simple as this, remember to go to

```
File > Manage > Security > [Account] > "Edit the privilege set"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the most common problem is that the field is missing from the FileMaker layout and the best way to check is to open the layout in FileMaker and make sure this is not the case. Note that FileMaker could have more than one layout with the same name.

The next thing to check, in FileMaker find the same record as the one you are viewing in PHP and make sure the data is not actually missing from the record.

Check the fields with missing data. They could be from a related table. If it is the case you need different syntax to reference them.

Finally, in FilerMaker change the fields into Edit Boxes. If they are drop-downs, they might have to be retrieved with a different method.

Comment: Yeah I ended up running through this checklist myself. I was going crazy! The final solution was that half of my fields were missing a read privilege in the account I use for PHP access.